# Convert dot to comma in input type=number

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to come up with a solution for converting dot to comma in an input field with `type="number"`, using either JS or JQuery.

The problem is two-fold:

1) It needs to replace the dot no matter where it is located in the input field. Values can be for example:

```
0.50

.45

12.45

12.
```

2) I can't use keyup as the trigger. This field is being populated by an externally connected scale, which sends the number, including the dot, in one go.

I hope someone can help with this, it's really doing my head in.

** UPDATE **
I managed to get this piece of code to work, but only if the input is TEXT. If I use NUMBER it just wipes the input clean (and I need it to be NUMBER in order to perform other on-page calculations with the number).

```
document.getElementById('purchaseQuantity').addEventListener('input', function() {
  document.getElementById('purchaseQuantity').value = this.value.replace('.', ',')
});
```

Thanks,

Comment: Get the value before it is set to the input and change it there

Comment: can you use `onchange` event ?

Comment: Weedoze, How can I do this? It is inserted directly into the input, in the same manner as a Ctrl+V would do.

Gulfaran, onchange only triggers when a user navigates away from the input field, no?

Answer (score 1):

Use a hidden field with name and update the value within the handler.

```js
document.getElementById('number').addEventListener('input', function() {
  document.getElementById('hidden').value = this.value.replace('.', ',')
})
```

```html
<input type="number" id="number" />
<input type="hidden" name="number" id="hidden" />
```

Comment: Hi, this doesn't work for me? Even here on Stackoverflow, I click "Run code snippet", but when I put in a number with a dot nothing changes..

Comment: @AndreasBB : the value will update in the hidden field

Answer (score 0):

`var numComma = (value.toString()).replace(".", ",")`

Convert the number to string and then use `.replace(".",",")`